# How do I save the state of the treeview nodes (expanded/collapsed) between postbacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**DUPE** [C# Treeview state expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516192/c-treeview-state-expanded)

See above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that depends upon your treeview. The Telerik treeview does this via viewstate...

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/treeview/how-do-i-maintain-treeview-state-after-postback.aspx

... and this following post suggests a way of hand-rolling this...

http://blog.binaryocean.com/PermaLink,guid,23808645-43b5-4e2a-afb1-53dc8da35636.aspx

I've not tried either solution, so can't vouch for them, but they look promising.

Comment: Here's a cached version of the second link that is broken: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ddshVGA_8F0J:blog.binaryocean.com/default,date,2006-01-19.aspx+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=opera

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable view state for your tree view control.

Answer (score 0):

Use this .Save it in a view state on post back and use the view state to render it in the same state

```
<% List<TreeViewItem> checkedNodes = ViewData["TreeView1_checkedNodes"] as ist<TreeViewItem>; %>

<%= Html.Telerik().TreeView()
.Name("Tree")    
.ShowCheckBox(true)
.ClientEvents(ev => ev.OnChecked("OnCheck")
)
.BindTo(Model, mappings =>
{
    mappings.For<GridWithWindow.Jar>(binding => binding
        .ItemDataBound((item, jag) =>
            {
                item.Text = jag.TreeName;
                item.Value = jag.TreeName;

                if (checkedNodes != null)
                {
                    var checkedNode = checkedNodes
                                        .Where(e => e.Value.Equals("ddd"))
                                        .FirstOrDefault();
                    item.Checked = checkedNode != null ? checkedNode.Checked : false;
                }                    

            })
            .Children(jag => jag.FirstLevelIList));
    mappings.For<GridWithWindow.Jaguar.FirstLevel>(binding => binding
        .ItemDataBound((item, frst) =>
            {
                item.Text = frst.FirstLevelName;
                item.Value = frst.FirstLevelName;
            })
```